# How to set alias for a non web-acessible folder in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Hi I made a module in my Yii2 basic application. I need a path to display an image in my view, but I can't get the path right. My web-accessible directory is located in `C:/xampp/htdocs/basic` and only containing Yii2 entry script and published assets folder. All my application files are located in a non web-accessible directory `C:/xampp/htdocs/gbia`, which is in the same directory level (or some might call it 'sibling directory') with the folder where my Yii2 entry script and published assets are located.

I made an upload path param in my model and it's getting called by the method from the controller.

I tried these in separate occasion after a research :

```
Yii::$app->params['uploadUrl'] = Yii::$app->urlManager->baseUrl . '/uploads/batam/';
Yii::$app->params['uploadUrl'] = Yii::$app->request->baseUrl  . '/uploads/batam/';
Yii::$app->params['uploadUrl'] = Yii::getAlias('@web').'/uploads/batam/';
```

and also `Url::base()`, `Url::base(true)` 
But they all didn't return my baseUrl. They only echoed out `/uploads/batam/`, without the base URL, as if the base Url returns NULL.

lastly, I tried echoing `Yii::$app->homeUrl;` and it returns `/`

I'm still learning and as to my knowledge, `@web` refer to the directory where our index.php entry script was, please correct me if I'm wrong. So I tried to solve the problem by making a new alias in my config :

```
'aliases'=>[
'@batam'=> Yii::$app->getAlias('@webroot') . '/../gbia/uploads/batam',
],
```

and also tried with `getAlias('@web')` but they both return this error : `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAlias() on null`

I also tried this in my aliases:

```
'@batam'=> Yii::$app->basePath.'/../gbia/uploads/batam',
```

but also failed. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: `Yii::$app->getAlias('@webroot')` should be `Yii::getAlias('@webroot')`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I got this error : `Fatal error: Uncaught yii\base\InvalidArgumentException: Invalid path alias: @webroot in C:\xampp\htdocs\gbia\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php:154 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gbia\config\web.php(21): yii\BaseYii::getAlias('@webroot') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\index.php(10): require('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\gbia\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php on line 154`

Comment: Is it correct to create `@batam` alias from the `webroot` path, than go upside one directory by using `/,,/` , than go to the non web accessible directory `gbia` like I was trying to do ?

Comment: added an answer see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

The aliases `@webroot` and `@web` are not available in the config file. The reason being the application run after requiring the config file and the aliases are set in the in the `bootstrap()` of the `yii\web\Application`. Look into your entry script file `web\index.php` if you are using basic app it should be like below

```
<?php

// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';

$config = require __DIR__ . '/../config/web.php';

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

and you can see that the config file is required before initializing the application, hence the aliases `@webroot` and `@web` not being set yet are not accessible.

So what yo uneed to do is you have to set the aliases to be used in the config file and for that you can do the following

- Create a file named `config/aliases.php`.
- Set the required aliases in the file.
  `Yii::setAlias('@webroot',dirname(dirname(__DIR__)).'/web');`
- Require the above file in the entry script `index.php` before the `config/web.php` file and that's it now you can access the alias in the config file, your entry script should now look like below

```php
<?php

// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../config/aliases.php';
$config = require __DIR__ . '/../config/web.php';

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

### Update

For uploading the images to outside the document root i would suggest that you make a symlink inside the `webroot` which will be pointing to your folder outside the document root, and point your alias to that symlink, this way you would be saving the images outside the document root and wont have to go through all this.

Comment: I did as what you told with this path adjustment : `Yii::setAlias('@webroot',dirname(dirname(__DIR__));` It's without `web` because I'd removed the folder. 

I echo out my `@webroot` and it shows `C:/xampp/htdocs/basic` as I've set in my `http.conf` as my document root. But when I set my alias in web config `'@batam'=> Yii::getAlias('@webroot') . '/../gbia/uploads/batam/',` it echoed out this : `/../batam/site` (`batam` is my module name ,btw)

I'm trying to set alias to a non-web acessible directory `C:/xampp/htdocs/gbia/uploads/batam/` where my image were stored

Comment: I tried another approach by using yii2 predefined path `@app` in my params for uploading path : `Yii::$app->params['uploadUrl2'] =Yii::getAlias('@app'). '/uploads/batam/';` because `@app` pointed to my non-accessible directory, but I got error in console : `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/gbia/uploads/batam/ImageName.jpg`

The path seems ok to me but I don't know what's wrong.

This is how I display the image in my view : `echo Html::img($model->getImageUrl(), [ 'class'=>'thing','height'=>'auto', 'width'=>'100%', 'max-width'=>'1080px']);`

Comment: This is what my `$model->getImageUrl()` did, simply `return Yii::$app->params['uploadUrl2'] . $image;`

Comment: I never used symlink before, Where in the webroot should I put the `symlink()` ? Is it in my Yii entry script `index.php` ? Is this the correct way to use it : `symlink ( __DIR__ . '/gbia', $uploadLink )`

where `gbia` is the folder which is on the same directory level with my webroot (outside of webroot but on the same level)

Then I make this alias in config :
`@alias => readlink($uploadLink) . '/uploads/batam/' `

Where `uploads/batam` is the folder path I want to keep my uploaded files. `readlink($uploadLink)` here will point to the folder outside of my webroot.

Is this correct?

Comment: symlinks should be inside your `web` directory and should point to the directory outside the root directory @codejunkie

Comment: Thanks for your help, I decided to moved the `uploads` folder into the web-accessible directory to avoid complexity.

Comment: all you had to do was to create a symlink in the web folder that points to your actual uploads folder  where ever it is , a symlink acts similar to a folder for your app you dont have to do anything else than that

Answer (score 0):

You need to register it in bootstrap.php file

```
Yii::setAlias('@webroot', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/path/to/webroot');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I thought `@webroot` is a predefined alias which point to Yii2 entry script so it doesn't need to be set/register anymore? I'm trying to make `@batam` alias (which define a path of my non-webaccessible directory) by defining it from `@webroot` then from there I go up one directory and then access my non-web`gbia` directory